# Best way to find all values of two variables that have a certain sum

Tags: c#, algorithm, search

I have two variables i, j both unknown at run-time. I have two limits maximumi and maximumj respectively whose values are known such that i is between 0 and its respective limit (same for j). I have another variable, which is known at runtime and is the sum of i and j. I need to find all values of i and j that have a sum equal to the variable sum before performing a certain calculation using i and j. What I've tried is to use one nested for loop and simply brute-force my way to finding the values of i and j, so that for every possible i add every possible j and check if the sum is equal to sum. This works great for small limits, but as my limits approach infinity, the algorithm grows hideously. I have a threshold of 3 seconds to find those numbers. Is there a recommended data structure for my situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var sum = 99999999;
var max = 60000000;
var min = 10000000;

var i = max;
var j = sum - max;

var result = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
while (j >= min && j =< max)
{
    result.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(i, j));
    i--;
    j++;
}
```

No need to bruteforce as this can be calculated easily. Runs smooth within few millisecs, even with large gaps between max and min.

Comment: May even be worthwhile to update this to used deferred execution. If the numbers are particularly large, it will produce a huge list which would be a waste if all you intend to do is to work with a subset (say, the first 100,000) EDIT: And if you need a `Count` of them, since the number of combinations is a constant, you can return a composite object containing the `IEnumerable` and the count value.

Comment: Yep, that's fast if ever I saw it. Thanks. Ditched the list, its unnecessary for my needs. Besides, I don't have that kind of space.

Comment: @TheJackal The maximum values can be different? There's no minimum in the OP?

Comment: @laune the limits for i and j can be different. the minimum for both i and j is zero

Answer (score 2):

You need only one loop (for example `i` from `0` to `sum`) and `j` will be always equal to `sum - i`. There is no need to create nested loop for `j`, since its value is always known.

```
int sum = 1337;
for (int i = 0; i <= sum; i++)
{
   var j = sum - i;
   Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", i, j, sum);
}
```

Comment: thanks kostov for this. This is also a powerful gem of code. Gave faster times on much larger limits.                                    `int sum = 1337777777;                                                             for (int i = 0; i <= limiti; i++){ if(sum - i >= 0 && sum - i <= limitj) {var j = sum - i;}`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply enumerate over them?

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> options = new List<Tuple<int, int>();
for(int a=0; a < sum; a++)
    options.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(a, sum-a));
```

Adjust for your boundaries, of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
int min( int a, int b ){ return a < b ? a : b; }
int max( int a, int b ){ return a > b ? a : b; }

void pairs( int sum, int maxi, int maxj ){
  if( maxi + maxj < sum ) return;
  maxi = min( maxi, sum );
  maxj = min( maxj, sum );
  for( int i = max( 0, sum - maxj); i <= min( maxi, sum ); i++ ){
    std::cout << "i=" << i << ", j=" << (sum - i) << std::endl;
  }
}
```